# canon pixma mg2440 scanner not working with xsane

Tags: canon, pixma, xsane

I have got the canon pixma printer/scanner , tried installing drivers from cd, it didn't work, from canon website, i couldn't install ,  xsane doesn't see the scanner , however the printer is working. any solution for fixing this? thank you

Comment: thank you , I downloaded the drives from canon and now it's opening from gimp.

Comment: you should give yourself a detailed answer below and mark it as definitive. you could provide a link or other details on the Canon drivers you used. I think they would work in my case, I have a similar problem in this question [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/723592/47206). I have also used  Canon drivers for the scanner - scangearmp-common and scangearmp-mg2400series - and the scanner is not seen)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the drivers from Canon, the ScanGear application is there too, and that's all you need.

Run `scangearmp`. That command can be added into a `.desktop` file, like [so](https://askubuntu.com/a/725412/47206).

It can be run from within Gimp, but scanning is not dependent on that.